# Tkinter bug: button on the same rows coalesce

Tags: python, tkinter

I have `tkinter_sandbox.py`:

```python
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
root = Tk()
root.title("Tkinter bug?")
mainframe = ttk.Frame(root)
mainframe.grid(column=0, row=0)
buttons = []

for i in range(3):
    buttons.append(ttk.Button(mainframe, text="1", command=lambda:print(i)))
    buttons[i].grid(row=1, column=i+1)

root.mainloop()
```

Then, I execute the code using `python tkinter_sandbox.py` on cmd. A window pops up, and I click on the buttons from left to right once.

The output on the console is `2 2 2`, whereas `0 1 2` is expected.

[image]

Specs:

- Python 3.5.1
- Tkinter version 8.6
- Windows 7 Enterprise

Comment: I find the downvote and duplication mark unreasonably dismissive. The OP may not realize that the lambda function inside the loop is the cause of the problem. (In fact, I think he suspected that it was a bug in Tkinter.) IMHO it is more appropriate with an answer pointing out the problem with the lambda.

Answer (score 3):

the problem is that you need to pass the arguments through the lamba declaration:

```
command=lambda:print(i)
```

needs to be:

```
command=lambda i=i:print(i)
```

so complete code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
root = Tk()
root.title("Tkinter bug?")
mainframe = ttk.Frame(root)
mainframe.grid(column=0, row=0)
buttons = []

for i in range(3):
    buttons.append(ttk.Button(mainframe, text="1", command=lambda i=i:print(i)))
    buttons[i].grid(row=1, column=i+1)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2):

You're using `i` to create the buttons and it's being updated to a new value by the command is taking place.

Fixed code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
root = Tk()
root.title("Tkinter bug?")
mainframe = ttk.Frame(root)
mainframe.grid(column=0, row=0)
buttons = []

for i in range(3):
    buttons.append(ttk.Button(mainframe, text="1", command=lambda x=i:print(x)))
    buttons[i].grid(row=1, column=i+1)

root.mainloop()
```